# Data types for single chars (or fixed-length strings) in Cassandra

Tags: string, cassandra, cql

My dataset has several string columns which their maximum string lengths are known, and some of them are only a single char.  I tried to use varchar with specified length like `varchar(5)` to store them, but the CQL (v1.2.8) seems not recognize such syntax:

```
cqlsh:so> create table test_table (uid int primary key, states varchar(2));
Bad Request: line 1:60 mismatched input '(' expecting ')'
```

If CQL does support fixed-length text, can I know where did I do wrong in table creation? If not, can I know which data types should I use for storing short strings (with length less than 5) or fixed-length strings Cassandra in order to make CQL easier to perform optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CQL doesn't support fixed length strings.
RI know it's a large document, but you should read through [the CQL docs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#types).

And the syntax is just `varchar` without the **( )**

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    username varchar,
    password varchar,
    email varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much~ I did read the CQL docs but just want to double check whether I am right on this and how people work-around with this.